# How to multiply rows and columns in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to multiply numbers in rows and in columns using nested for loops.

I have a sum of column, and I'm trying to use the same logic for multiplying rows but without any success...

```
$nxmArr = array(array());

$rows = 4;
$cols = 4;

$m = 0;

$colSum = 0;
$rowSum = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
  $colSum = 1;
  for($j = 0; $j < $cols; $j++) {
    $m++;
    $colSum *= $m;
    echo "$m ";
  }
  echo "Column Sum: $colSum<br>";
}
```

I have a list of numbers from 1 to 16, and I'm getting right results for every column, but when I try with rows I'm not getting right results...

Comment: *I'm creating an empty matrix array*, so what are you actually doing the calculations on?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: This is for columns 1 2 3 4 Column Sum: 24
5 6 7 8 Column Sum: 1680
9 10 11 12 Column Sum: 11880
13 14 15 16 Column Sum: 43680... now I should to that for rows, like for example first row is 1 * 5 * 9 * 13 .etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficulty is that you are not adding up values from the matrix, you are just calculating the value in each column as you go along (the value `$m`).

This sets the values in the first set of loops and sets the values, then does the calculations using these values

```
$rows = 4;
$cols = 4;
$nxmArr = [];
$value = 1;
for ( $row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++ )  {
    for ( $col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++ )  {
        $nxmArr[$row][$col] = $value++;
    }
}

// Start with rows...
for ( $row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++ )  {
    $rowSum = 1;
    // For each column
    for ( $col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++ )  {
        echo $nxmArr[$row][$col]." ";
        $rowSum *= $nxmArr[$row][$col];
    }
    echo " sum-".$rowSum.PHP_EOL;
}
/* Generates
1 2 3 4  sum-24
5 6 7 8  sum-1680
9 10 11 12  sum-11880
13 14 15 16  sum-43680
*/
// Then columns
for ( $col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++ )  {
    $colSum = 1;
    for ( $row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++ )  {
        echo $nxmArr[$row][$col]." ";
        $colSum *= $nxmArr[$row][$col];
    }
    echo " sum-".$colSum.PHP_EOL;
}
/* Generates
1 5 9 13  sum-585
2 6 10 14  sum-1680
3 7 11 15  sum-3465
4 8 12 16  sum-6144
 */
```

Comment: How can do that but without array function array_chunk or any other array function..just pure logic?

Comment: Thank you Nigel for your help

Comment: Just one more question... how can I add empty associative array in this code and make calculation inside that array, like I did on my example code that I've shared...

Comment: Yes, but I need on base of dimensions for rows and columns, I need to fill empty array with those values, and after filling array I need to multiply every row and every column...

Comment: Yes, but you used functions like array_chunk, but the idea is to not use any of functions, just pure logic...like in my example code